# How exactly is "another" an ordinal number? Please give examples

Tags: ordinal-numbers

In my Collins Grammar book, it says that *another* can in ways be an ordinal number. I understand how *next* or *last* can be ordinal numbers because they point to something in an ordered sequence. Instead of saying "The second place winner is..." I can say "The next winner is..." But I don't fully understand how "another" can be an ordinal.

Please include examples, thank you!

Comment: Doesn't it work the same way as _next_? _Give me an item...and the next...and another..._

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! The way you simply explained it with an example was perfect. I just couldn't understand it before, but now that you gave a real life example, it makes total sense. Cheers.

(Edit: feel free to repost as an answer and I can select it.)

Comment: I suggest you get another grammar book!

Comment: @BillJ Are you saying that _another_ cannot function as a ordinal number or that the book should have explained it better?

Comment: @KillingTime *Another* in your sentence doesn't necessarily mean the next item waiting to be given (although obviously it will be the next you give); it could be **any** item still ungiven. In that case, it is not functioning in the same way as *next.*

Comment: Yet [Collins CoBuild Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/another) classifies all listed usages as determiner usages.

Comment: A determinative, but not an ordinal number.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what is meant by "ordinal number"

OED:

> I. **A second**, further, additional.

**1.** One more, one further; originally **a second of two things**; subsequently extended to anything additional or remaining beyond those already considered; an additional.

> b. with n. not expressed. (Pl. others.)

2021 The Butterfly Garden: By Sophie Anderson

> ‘Here, let me,’ Erin said, tipping a white tablet into Maggie’s
> hand.
>
> 'I need two, give me another.’ Erin tipped the second pill into her palm and held onto the bottom of the glass as Maggie took it to her lips.*

However, in the broader sense, you can see the parallel between "Give me a third... a fourth... a fifth... another."